# Using gdal_calc.py from the OSGeoW4 Shell

Tags: qgis, python, osgeo4w, gdal-calc, environment-variable

I want to run gdal_calc.py from within the OSGeoW4 shell but am having only limited success.

Firstly, if I type in `-o help` gdal_calc does not appear in the list, as show below, whereas I have seen examples where people have run the same command and the file was listed. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here?

[image]

Secondly, I can only run the command if I include the path as shown in the example below:

```
python C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python39\Scripts\gdal_calc.py -A D:\input.tif --calc="A==3"  --NoDataValue=0 --outfile=test.tif
```

Is there a way that I can avoid having to point the command using the path to gdal_calc.py? I've been looking at the environment variables setting and have gotten confused. I have added the path and and have pushed it up to the top but I still can't run the command without having to use the complete path to point to the file.

[image]

Forgive my ignorance in how environment variables work and how GDAL and Python work together.

Answer (score 1):

I have two OSGeo4W installation and only one is listing the gdal_calc utility. However, even the version that does not list gdal_calc with o-help has directory C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\Scripts included in PATH

`PATH=C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qt5\bin;C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\Scripts;C:\OSGeo4W\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WBem`.

The scripts directory contains

- gdal_calc.py
- gdal_calc.bat

The contents of gdal_calc.bat are

```
@echo off
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat"
python "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python39\Scripts\gdal_calc.py" %*
```

The gdal_calc.bat is made for you, so write just `gdal_calc`. There are similar convenience scripts for other Python utilities.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the gdal python lib from the Osgeo4w installer to be able to use the python scripts.